# Is it possible to define an efficient hyper-operation sequence as a recursive squaring function over 2-adics in Haskell?

Tags: algorithm, haskell, math, functional-programming, binary

Let's define a 2-adic in Haskell as its infinite binary expansion:

```hs
data Adic = O Adic | I Adic deriving Show
```

We can represent finite numbers as follows:

```hs
zero = O zero
one  = I zero
neg1 = I neg1
```

And we can easily define `Inc` and `Add` for `Adic`:

```hs
inc :: Adic -> Adic
inc (O a) = I a
inc (I a) = O (Inc a)

add :: Adic -> Adic -> Adic
add (O a) (O b) = O (add a b)
add (O a) (I b) = I (add a b)
add (I a) (O b) = I (add a b)
add (I a) (I b) = I (inc (add a b))
```

We can convert adics to ints follows:

```hs
a2i :: Int -> Adic -> Int
a2i 1 (O x) = 0
a2i 0 (I x) = -1
a2i s (O x) = 2 * i2a (s - 1) x
a2i s (I x) = 2 * i2a (s - 1) x + 1
```

This allows us to do basic arithmetic. For example:

```
print $ a2i 64 (add one neg1)
```

Would print `0`, after computing `1 + -1` on 2-adics.

Now, I'm interested in the hyper-operation sequence function, i.e.:

```hs
hyp :: Int -> Adic -> Adic -> Adic
hyp 0 a b = add a b
hyp 1 a b = mul a b
hyp 2 a b = exp a b
hyp 3 a b = tet a b
...
```

An efficient way to implement it is by generalizing the exponentiation by squaring algorithm, as follows:

```hs
hyp :: Int -> Adic -> Adic -> Adic
hyp 0 a b = add a b
hyp s a 1 = a
hyp s a (O b) = let r = hyp s a b       in hyp (s - 1) r r
hyp s a (I b) = let r = hyp s a (Inc b) in hyp (s - 1) r r
```

To visualize the function above, below is the evaluation of `hyp 2 4 4`, i.e., `4^4`:

```
4^4 =
4^2 * 4^2 =
4^1 * 4^1 * 4^1 * 4^1 =
4   * 4   * 4   * 4   =

4*4 * 4*4 =
(4*2 + 4*2) * (4*2 * 4*2) =
(4*1 + 4*1 + 4*1 + 4*1) * (4*1 + 4*1 + 4*1 + 4*1) =
(4   + 4   + 4   + 4)   * (4   + 4   + 4   + 4)   =

16*16 =
16*8 + 16*8 =
16*4 + 16*4 + 16*4 + 16*4 =
16*2 + 16*2 + 16*2 + 16*2 + 16*2 + 16*2 + 16*2 + 16*2 =
16*1 + 16*1 + 16*1 + 16*1 + 16*1 + 16*1 + 16*1 + 16*1 + 16*1 + 16*1 + 16*1 + 16*1 + 16*1 + 16*1 + 16*1 + 16*1 =
16   + 16   + 16   + 16   + 16   + 16   + 16   + 16   + 16   + 16   + 16   + 16   + 16   + 16   + 16   + 16   =

256
```

Sadly, the function above doesn't actually work, because the `hyp s a 1 = a` line attempts to match an `Adic` against the Int `1`, which makes no sense. What it should do, instead, is match against the 2-adic number 1. The problem is: *2-adics are infinite, so we can't match them*. We can't even create an `is one` function. As such, while the function above seems elegant and efficient, it, as far as I can tell, can't be constructed. **My question is: am I right in concluding `hyp` can't be implemented that way, or am I missing something?** Is there an alternative approach that would let this work?

Comment: This seems more like a meth/algorithm problem than a Haskell problem. Do you have an existing algorithm for p-adic hyperoperations that you want to port? If not, the mathematicians probably have better ideas than we do.

Comment: `inc (I a) = O a` seems wrong. Since `inc one = inc (I zero) = O zero` but `zero = 0 zero`.

Comment: How is `hyp s a b = hyp (s - 1) r r where r = hyp s a b` correct? Shouldn't it decrement `a` or `b`? Also I don't get where did you get `^2` from in the example.

Comment: Actually, what if you define a 2-adic number as a function from the same `s` you use in `a2i`? This way, worst case you could force evaluation of a number to some extent relative to `s`, so no information is lost.

Comment: Yes, lots of typos, sorry. Just typed this in one go at 4am before sleeping. Fixed.

Comment: @radrow yes, but then that won't be 2-adics anymore. For example, I believe you lose the ability to express fractions, if you have a finite representation. But as it was pointed on Reddit, I now see it is impossible to do what I asked. Which is underwhelming / weight, but I guess that's how things are.

Comment: What is (-1)^(-1) in 2-adics? Or do you only care about positive arguments of hyp?

Comment: @Li-yaoXia only care about the positive arguments for the sake of this question, yes, but one of the reasons I asked it to begin with was to gain an insight in questions like the one you just asked. If I'm not mistaken, it is possible to represent `i` on 3-adics, right?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it's about math, not programming; and math has proven no solution can exist.

Comment: @MaiaVictor What reddit? If you're cross-posting, please at least do it transparently and include a link.

Comment: @Bergi https://www.reddit.com/r/math/comments/zgqpb6/is_it_possible_to_define_an_efficient/